# Isolate string starting before specific string

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My string is as follows:

```
'NAME NAME NAME 400ML NAME CODE'
```

I need to identify `ML`, go left to catch all digits before that and stop on first `space` to get:

```
400ML
```

Current code I have:

```
 SUBSTR(FIELD,CHARINDEX('ML',FIELD), 2)
```

Comment: Why not just `regexp_substr(field, '\\d+ML')`? Are there any non-digit chars you need to match before `ML`?

Comment: No, only numbers are before ML but before number there might be a word that has `ML` stirng in it. That way number-ML will not be found in first place.  `NAMEML CODE MLNAME 400 ML CODE CODE`. This can help: `regexp_substr(REPLACE(field, ' ', ''), '\\d+ML')`

Comment: If there may be spaces between the number and `ML`, you may match them with `\s*`. Also, what is `ML` is part of a longer word? Try `regexp_substr(field, '\\d+\\s*ML\\b')`

Comment: Yes, @WiktorStribiżew - I forgot to mention the case with space between number and ML. Your solution work's perfectly!

Comment: Great, I posted a [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62960047/3832970) with an explanation and demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
regexp_substr(field, '\\d+\\s*ML\\b')
```

This regex will make sure the `ML` is matched as a whole word, and if there are any whitespaces between a number and `ML`, they will also be matched.

***See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2j5zJ/1)***.

**Regex details**

- `\d+`  - 1 or more digits
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `ML` - a string `ML`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Nice example of character class usage, especially the double backslashes, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(field, '[^ ]+ML')
```

Or for specifically alphanumeric characters:

```
select regexp_substr(field, '[a-zA-Z0-9]+ML')
```

If Snowflake is not greedy (which seems unlikely but is possible), then you can do:

```
select trim(regexp_substr(' ' || field, ' [a-zA-Z0-9]*ML'))
```

Comment: I noticed that `WORD-M 400ML CODE` returns `ML`

Comment: @marcin2x4 . . . Usually regular expression matching is greedy by default.  I am surprised this is not the case in Snowflake.  Here is an example of the code working:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8519d3a4b7d061eb22e4f72c1d6f2ea6.

Comment: try with `'WORD-ML 400ML CODE'` :)

Comment: @marcin2x4 . . . I would argue that it is doing the right thing.  But if you want to require at least one character then use `+` in the second method.

Answer (score 2):

To extract number with `ML` as suffix use

```
select regexp_substr(field, '[0-9]+ML')
```

EXPLANATION

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ML                       'ML'
```